# Why didn't the gladers try to use the lift to escape?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

When the Gladers were in the Glade in *The Maze Runner* and the lift came up carrying supplies and even another Glader, why couldn't the Gladers jump inside of the lift in order to escape? It would take them down to the lab where they came from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They actually tried that, but it is stated that the elevator would not go down when someone was in it. Thomas at one time starts inquiring about the possibility of doing just that.

> And what about the Box? Next time it comes up...

Here he's cut in mid sentence and Newt replies.

> No, we tried that. The Box won't go back down with someone in it.

Apparently Chancellor Ava Paige and the rest of her crew were watching if the gladers attempted to exploit this specific loop hole. You could find this conversation around the 20 minute mark of the movie.

Comment: Yeah, i read the book not long ago and you are right, but it wasn't Newt that said it, it was Chuck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have learned that they didn't try because they already tried it and it turns out that the kid that volunteered got sliced clean in half when he was abut 3 metres down from the box doors, he was going down by vines made by the Gladers.

Answer (score -1):

Because in the books and maybe in the movies, if people go in the elevator shaft, it won't go down and if someone jumps or goes down while the shaft is going down, they will be killed by saws or maybe some other way, but it will never work and there are gates when the shaft is not coming up to stop people from jumping down.

Answer (score -2):

They tried that. The lift wouldn't physically go down with weight in it. Also they tried with a hand made rope but weren't able to make it long enough. On another attempt to get down, a guy was asumed to have gone to his death by falling although the people at the top did not hear him land because of long way down. This happened after him trying to climb down. They all gave up after that

Comment: What does this add to the previous answer?